# Request.params is gone in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is there a way to access all request parameters, regardless of HTTP method? I have poured over the documentation and the api without finding a way in Play Framework 2.0.

I have a search on a site that accepts POST and GET. The custom tracking on the site examines all parameters passed in to determine the correct way to store tracking data.

In the Play Framework 1.2.x, I was able to access parameters from a request in a Controller with

```java
request.params.get("keywords")
request.params.get("location") 
request.params.all()
```

With Play Framework 2.0, this is no longer the case. The [Request](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request) no longer has the method `params`, only `queryString` and queryString only works with GET and not POST.

It is not feasible to define every single possible tracking parameter into the Controller Action, they are dynamic.

---

**UPDATE**: A possible work around is using [Body Parsers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaBodyParsers).

Depending on the content type of the request, the appropriate parser is used, e.g. *application/form-url-encoded* vs *application/json*

This is the crude Map that combines POST parameters and GET parameters, with GET parameters taking precedence.

```java
val params: collection.mutable.Map[String, Seq[String]] = collection.mutable.Map() 
params ++= request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.getOrElse[Map[String, Seq[String]]] { Map.empty } 
params ++= request.queryString
```

Comment: Action(parse.fooContentType) {...} is quite helpful, thanks for the Body parsers link!

Comment: Your answer should be split out as an answer, not as an edit of the original question.

Comment: I was hoping for a proper answer that was supported by the API instead of the crude fix I have working right now

Comment: @GeorgeStocker this question is very specific, complete, and fortunately has been updated with a useful answer. It astounds me that you would close such a question. In fact, before you closed the question it was praised by another in comments. I don't know which standards you think questions should adhere to, but stackoverflow is not an encyclopaedia, and closing such questions reflects poorly on yourself and demonstrates that experience and reputation are indicators for senility.

Comment: +1 for fabspro's insight -- this community is wonderful and definitely *not* wikishidia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Play 2.0 documentation doesn't explain this very well. Body parsers are an acceptable solution, but I've found `DynamicForm` to be much more lightweight and user friendly.

The documentation can be found [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html).

In particular, the `DynamicForm.bindFromRequest()` is a good place to start if you are trying to replace the old Play 1.0 `request.params.get()`.

Comment: In 2.1.0 (possibly 2.0 as well) I use form().bindFromRequest().get("param_key") to get individual request vars.

Comment: @fabspro  where is the form() method, which class or package should I import ?

Comment: @zjffdu form() method moved to play.data.Form.form() so you should use it as Form.form(). https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/documentation/manual/Migration.md#playmvccontrollerform-renamed-to-playdataformform

Answer (score 4):

```
ctx()._requestHeader().getQueryString("q").get();
```

this doesn't require any extra imports and should work straight out of bootstrapped controller.